# How to set threshold value in tomcat instance for jconsole monitoring

Tags: tomcat, jconsole, threshold

I wish  to monitor my tomcat instance with jconsole. I'm using tomcat in Redhat5.5. I have configured jmx in my tomcat instance, and now I am able to connect my tomcat instance via jconsole remotely. In the application level, I want to set the threshold value in my tomcat application instance for doing a manual GC. Can anyone  tell me how to set the threshold value in my tomcat application.

Thanks in Advance,
Dilip.